# LINQ CopyToDataTable -- Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Decimal'. Please use a nullable type

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset, nullable, dbnull

I am parsing two Excel files that contain many fields, most importantly TOTAL_DOLLARS and TOTAL_UNITS fields, that often have values, but some of them are left blank, or null.  I want to `JOIN` these two DataTables using LINQ where the `UPC` fields are equal.  However, I have run into the following error:

`Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Decimal'. Please use a nullable type`

This error occurs when I try to join the two tables because of the null fields.

My LINQ code is as follows:

```
Dim query = From c In dtDollars.AsEnumerable() _
      Join r In dtUnits.AsEnumerable() _
      On c.Field(Of String)("UPC") Equals r.Field(Of String)("UPC") _
      Select _
      New _
      With {.UPC = r.Field(Of String)("UPC"), .WIC_NUMBER = c.Field(Of String)("WIC_NUMBER"), _
      .WAG_ITEM_DESC = c.Field(Of String)("WAG_ITEM_DESC"), _
      .WAG_BRAND = c.Field(Of String)("WAG_BRAND"), .UOM = c.Field(Of String)("UOM"), _
      .GSK_PROMO_GRP = c.Field(Of String)("GSK_PROMO_GRP"), _
      .TOTAL_DOLLARS = c.Field(Of Decimal)("TOTAL_DOLLARS"), _
      .TOTAL_UNITS = r.Field(Of Integer)("TOTAL_UNITS"), _
      .WKND_DATE = c.Field(Of DateTime)("WKND_DATE")}
```

Comment: Does WKND_DATE always have a value? If not, that also needs to be nullable.

Comment: @flem Yes WKND_DATE actually does always have a value.  However, `WAG_ITEM_DESC`, `WAG_BRAND`, and `GSK_PROMO_GRP` do not.  Thank you for catching that.

Comment: So change the last line to: `.WKND_DATE = c.Field(Of DateTime?)("WKND_DATE")}`. This is not required on the string types as string allows nulls as it's a reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that WKND_DATE can also be null, get the field as a `Nullable(Of DateTime)` (`DateTime?`) like so:

```
Dim query = From c In dtDollars.AsEnumerable() _
   Join r In dtUnits.AsEnumerable() _
   On c.Field(Of String)("UPC") Equals r.Field(Of String)("UPC") _
   Select _
   New _
   With {.UPC = r.Field(Of String)("UPC"), .WIC_NUMBER = c.Field(Of String)("WIC_NUMBER"), _
   .WAG_ITEM_DESC = c.Field(Of String)("WAG_ITEM_DESC"), _
   .WAG_BRAND = c.Field(Of String)("WAG_BRAND"), .UOM = c.Field(Of String)("UOM"), _
   .GSK_PROMO_GRP = c.Field(Of String)("GSK_PROMO_GRP"), _
   .TOTAL_DOLLARS = c.Field(Of Decimal?)("TOTAL_DOLLARS"), _
   .TOTAL_UNITS = r.Field(Of Integer?)("TOTAL_UNITS"), _
   .WKND_DATE = c.Field(Of DateTime?)("WKND_DATE")}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have a different error.  See the extensive edits I made!

Comment: @user1496816 You should revert your radical edit as it invalidates the comments and answers to this question. Raise your new issue as a new question.